# Novel about genetically engineered children who don't need to sleep

Tags: novel, story-identification

A couple of years ago I read a review of an interesting novel, but I lost the details and have never read the book.

The background premise was that genetic engineering had progressed to the point where those who could afford it were "improving" their children. Many of these children had no need of sleep, with the abilty to be active 24 hours a day.

The story itself was set some 18-20 years later, when these children were entering adulthood and dealing with the bigotry and prejudice that arose when the "rest of us" started to realise what a competitive advantage the non-sleepers have.

Anyone recognise the novel?

Comment: One episode of The X Files features soldiers genetically adapted to avoid sleeping. but I didn't read the novel you mention

Comment: Heinlein's novel _Friday_ dealt extensively with (among other things) discrimination against those that were genetically engineered. The main character was genetically engineered and was cruelly discriminated against.

Comment: As a father of two young girls, I can confirm this is just natural and not the result of any genetic engineering.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

That sounds like [`Beggars in Spain`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beggars_in_Spain) by [Nancy Kress](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0380718774), which was originally published as a novella in 1991 and then expanded into a novel in 1993.

Comment: For reference: _Beggars in Spain_ can be found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beggars_in_Spain) and in [Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/Beggars-Spain-Trilogy-Nancy-Kress/dp/0380718774).

Comment: And there are a number of sequels, each more depressing than the next.  Utopia is achieved, and stupid humans turn it into dystopia.  I really liked it, but the dashing of hopes bugged me.